# Put MP3s on an Ipod Nano (3rd-gen) without iTunes

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I was given a 3rd-gen Nano and love it as a simple MP3 player but I'm not an Apple user and don't want to have to set up iTunes on Windows just to manage MP3s on the device.

Are there reputable tools out there which will let me drag & drop MP3s onto it like a regular MP3 player, or otherwise avoid the need for iTunes?

Comment: I believe the Standard version of WinAmp should be able to do this: http://www.winamp.com/media-player/all. There is a list of iPod management software here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_iPod_managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation, I came across [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com). It's s single, small .EXE and seems to work well without iTunes being installed.

Answer (score -1):

You need an alternative firmware, but since none is there you have to check site
http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/IpodNano3GPort
every other week.